# Looking through columns in Excel using VB.NET - Struggling to look past columns "AB" etc

Tags: vb.net, string, excel

Just had a question about my following code:

```
    For Each c In "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exsheet.Range((c & "5")).Value.ToString) Then
            pointer = pointer + 1
            XRisks(pointer) = exsheet.Range(c & "6").Value.ToString

        End If
    Next
```

In essence, the code looks through the 5th row of each column in an excel spreadsheet(called exsheet). If there is something in that cell, it saves it into the array (XRisks).

However, my excel spreadsheet goes past Z and continues to AA AB AC AD etc in the column headings, which means, with the code I have at the moment, it stops reading columns after column Z.

I tried adding        & "AA" & "AB" & "AC" etc to the end of my alphabet string but all this did was saved A again, then A again, then A again, then B again as it is just looking at each character in my string.

Hope I have described that enough. Thanks in advance!

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.Cells` instead of `.Range` with an index rather than letters.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exsheet.Cells(5, i).Value.ToString) Then
        ...
    Next
```

To iterate over all columns, you *can* try usedRange. This may be insecure, however, since the usedRange does not necessarily start on the first column if that is empty (that said, with most table-like sheets it is safe enough).

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To exsheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(exsheet.Cells(5, i).Value.ToString) Then
        ...
    Next
```

Comment: Hi again, thanks for the response, I am getting "NullReference Exception was unhandled" error over the "If not string..." line

Comment: Got to be something in your code, it has nothing to do with deciding between .Range and .Cells.